# if a positive number is equal to its reverse

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, reverse

I'm making a program to receive a positive number and output "yes" if it's equal to its reverse;
otherwise, output "no".

What I've done so far:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="column1">
    <div class="input">
      <button onclick="problem()"> Run the program </button>
    </div>
    <strong><p id="output"> </p></strong>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
function problem() {

  var outputObj = document.getElementById("output");

  var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));
 
  
outputObj.innerHTML = "number: " + a + "<br><br>";

var reverse = 0;

while (a > 0){
  num = a % 10;  // the last digit
  reverse = (reverse *10) + num; // calculating the reverse
  a = Math.floor(a / 10); // go to next digit
}

if ( reverse == a){
  outputObj.innerHTML = "yes";
}

else {
outputObj.innerHTML = "no";
}

  outputObj.innerHTML =  outputObj.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + "program ended";
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function isPalindrome(number){
  return +number.toString().split("").reverse().join("") === number
}
```

Art for art

```js
function palindrom(x)
{
  let len = Math.floor(Math.log(x)/Math.log(10) +1);
  while(len > 0) {
    let last = Math.abs(x - Math.floor(x/10)*10);
    let first = Math.floor(x / Math.pow(10, len -1));
    if(first != last){
      return false;
    }
    x -= Math.pow(10, len-1) * first ;
    x = Math.floor(x/10);
    len -= 2;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to convert it to a string. Can you answer based on what I have uploaded. Thank

Comment: @SinaHeidari Just so it is clear, although the number is converted to a string, split, reversed, and joined, there is a `+` in front which converts it back to a `Number` (rather than `string`). Therefore, due to its simplicity, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: in most case is better to write clean and easy to understand therefore maintenance code that to find the faster solution. If would some wrong in second solution most people together with me tomorrow will have problem to find bug and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You should search for plaindromic numbers. For example [the following code](https://dev.to/acupoftee/leetcode-palindrome-number-w-fun-javascript-mathematical-approach-1obi):

```
const isPalindrome = x => {
    if (x < 0) return false

    let reversed = 0, y = x

    while (y > 0) {
        const lastDigit = y % 10
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit
        y = (y / 10) | 0
    }
    return x === reversed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isPalindrome = num => {
    const len = Math.floor(Math.log10(num));
    let sum = 0;
    for(let k = 0; k <= len; k++) {
        sum += (Math.floor(num / 10 ** k) % 10) * 10 ** (len - k);
    }
    return sum === num;
 }
 console.log(isPalindrome(12321));
```